# Sabre EnhancedAirTicket REST API error: UNABLE TO TICKET - NEED AUTOVALIDATION IN TJR-0031

Tags: rest, sabre

I'm trying to call an API to get ticket on Sabre. This is the request:

```
{
  "AirTicketRQ": {
    "version": "1.2.1",
    "targetCity": "XXXX",
    "DesignatePrinter": {
      "Printers": {
        "Ticket": {
          "CountryCode": "VN"
        }
      }
    },
    "Ticketing": [
      {
        "PricingQualifiers": {
          "PriceQuote": []
        }
      }
    ],
    "Itinerary": {
      "ID": "XXXXXX"
    },
    "PostProcessing": {
      "GhostTicketCheck": {
        "numAttempts": 10,
        "waitInterval": 10000
      },
      "EndTransaction": {
        "Source": {
          "ReceivedFrom": "TEST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I received response with errors: `AirTicketLLS failed for /Ticketing[1] with Cause: AirTicketLLSRQ: UNABLE TO TICKET - NEED AUTOVALIDATION IN TJR-0031`

```
{
  "AirTicketRS": {
    "ApplicationResults": {
      "status": "Incomplete",
      "Error": [
        {
          "type": "Application",
          "timeStamp": "2022-03-14T14:50:52.532+07:00",
          "SystemSpecificResults": [
            {
              "Message": [
                {
                  "code": "ERR.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
                  "content": "No new tickets have been issued"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Warning": [
        {
          "type": "Application",
          "timeStamp": "2022-03-14T14:50:51.823+07:00",
          "SystemSpecificResults": [
            {
              "Message": [
                {
                  "code": "WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
                  "content": "AirTicketLLS failed for /Ticketing[1] with Cause: AirTicketLLSRQ: UNABLE TO TICKET - NEED AUTOVALIDATION IN TJR-0031"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Application",
          "timeStamp": "2022-03-14T14:50:52.532+07:00",
          "SystemSpecificResults": [
            {
              "Message": [
                {
                  "code": "WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR",
                  "content": "TicketingDocumentServicesRQ: No new tickets have been issued"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://api.test.sabre.com/v1.2.1/air/ticket"
    },
    {
      "rel": "linkTemplate",
      "href": "https://api.test.sabre.com/<version>/air/ticket"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what is the issue and I can't find any document that mentions `AUTOVALIDATION` on Sabre website.

Please tell me what is wrong with my reservation and how to fix it.

FYI, I received this warning after CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ:

```
{
  "ApplicationResults": {
    "status": "Complete",
    "Success": [
        {
          "timeStamp": "2022-03-14T14:44:10.201+07:00"
        }
      ],
      "Warning": [
        {
          "type": "BusinessLogic",
          "timeStamp": "2022-03-14T14:44:10.12+07:00",
          "SystemSpecificResults": [
            {
              "Message": [
                {
                  "code": "WARN.SWS.HOST.WARNING_RESPONSE",
                  "content": "EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dat. According to the service response, you may not be able to issue using this PCC, in which case you'll need to activate the AutoVal. The process can be found at central.sabre.com under the Format Finder.